# Outlook hangs for several minutes when viewing Stack Exchange newsletter

Tags: bug, newsletter

Every time I click on a *Stack Exchange* newsletter mail item

[image: item in Inbox]

my Outlook hangs for several minutes.

[image: process bar]

I am using Windows 7 64-bit and Outlook 2013 64-bit:
[image: Microsoft Outlook version description]

The preview of the e-mail is enough to trigger the crash. I did not double click on the e-mail to open it in a popup.

After waiting for several minutes it seems that several images have not been loaded.

[image: screen shot with missing images]

Could it be that the service provided by `i.stack.imgur.com` takes a long time to answer the requests from Outlook?

Comment: For the record, Thunderbird does not have any such problem. Can you get a Wireshark capture and tell us what the HTTP traffic looks like? At the moment this is something of a vague question that can probably not be answered at the level of detail given.

Comment: It's because they're protocol-relative URLs. Outlook doesn't handle that very well, it interprets them as `file://`.

Comment: @Stijn, because of this problem I consider to unsubscribe and probably other outlook users will also do this. Since it is not easy to realize a change within outlook, is it possible to realize a change to how to the stack exchange newsletter is setup.

Comment: @Ruut sure it's possible. But I have the feeling you confuse me for a dev, I'm just a user like you :)

Answer (score -1):

If that popup is to be believed, somebody screwed up and used UNC/SMB paths in the newsletter (`\\i.stack.imgur.com`). SMB traffic is dropped by most ISPs and corporate firewalls due to security concerns (including use by worms/viruses like Blaster) - hence the timeout.

Comment: Actually, it's MS screwing up by the numbers mis-interpreting the email.